# Spread array as dictionary key

Tags: python

Consider the following dict:

```
{
    "a" : {
        "b" : [
            entry,
            entry,
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to address each entry given a key in the form `"a.b"`?
Ideally one could write something like `dict[*("a.b".split("."))]` and get `dict["a"]["b"]`, but I have found no way to do it in Python yet.

---

### Edit 2

Since no one seems to really care about quality code, I ended up using a plain old for loop:

```
data = { "a" : { "b" : "foo" } }
key = "a.b"

d = data
for k in key.split("."):
    d = d[k]

d == data["a"]["b"] # True
```

---

### Edit 3

Comments contain a valid solution:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce  # forward compatibility for Python 3

data = { "a" : { "b" : "foo" } }
key = "a.b"

d = reduce(operator.getitem, key.split("."), data)

d == data["a"]["b"] # True
```

However, apart from this, I guess there is no way to exploit some language feature to do that, which kind of was the original question.

Comment: *Now* it's the correct duplicate.

Comment: @deceze No, it is not, it's a dict, not a class. In fact, it fails with error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'`. I will dive into `operator` to see if it has something for dictionaries.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, something about this question is bad luck. ***NOW*** it's the correct duplicate.

Comment: @deceze **NOW** we are talking, thanks for pointing it out. For the records, it's `reduce(operator.getitem, key.split("."), data)`. I think this would deserve an answer.

Comment: It already *has* an answer. In the duplicate.

Comment: At least remove the two wrong ones, they are misleading. Many thanks, today I learned something.